# Copy column of filtered cells and paste to different column

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I am currently working on a code to copy the filtered results of column CJ and paste them in column F. When I attempt to paste it is only pasting in the unfiltered areas and is removing the rest of the column's cells. Any idea of the correct code?

```
With ActiveSheet
    With Intersect(.Range("CJ:CJ"), .UsedRange)
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With
End With
ActiveSheet.Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
_Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: you _want_ to copy the hidden rows?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, I do not want to copy the hidden rows. I just want to copy the data in the filtered column and paste it to column F in the corresponding filtered cells.

Comment: @BruceWayne edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i = 1 to ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("C" & i).entireRow.hidden = False then Range("F" & i).value = Range("C" & i).value
Next i
```

Comment: I am getting an error "cannot find hidden property in specified range"

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `EntireRow`. Try now

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it works now! Is there any way it could be formatted off only the Visible Cells so it doesn't have to loop through the entire table? There are 70,000+ rows.

Comment: @papacoolaid666 - You could use the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` of Range. I.e. `Set myRng = Range("C1:C1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) // For each cel in myRng // ...`

Comment: Actually when I run the code it replaces the entire F column with the entire CJ column. Is there a way to make it only replace the cells that show up when filtered?

Comment: Maybe use `If Range("Column you filter on" & i).value = "Value you filter on"` instead of `EntireRow.hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code I found that satisfies the filtered copy & paste.

Thanks!

```
Sub CopyPasteFormula()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long
Dim PasteRng As Range
Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
LRow = Ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set PasteRng = Ws.Range("H1:H" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Ws.Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```